# golang: how to replace "\n" with "<br>"

Tags: html, replace, go

I tried to do it using `strings.Replace(s,"\n","<br>",-1);`
But the result is something different which could be displayed as `<br>` in a web browser but is in fact not `"<br>"`. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

My primary goal is to change the end of line character from a `<textarea>` into a `<br>` tag in html.

Any clue would be welcome, thanks in advance.

PS:

Q: Are you trying to get it from database?

A: Yeah, I get the string from GAE's database, and then replace `\n` with `<br>`. Is there anything different with string from database?

Comment: I did what you wrote (`strings.Replace(s,"\n","<br>",-1)`) and I got a `<br>` in place of the `"\n"`. Why do you say you don't get "<br>" ? What do you do later with that string ?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch form a database?

Comment: I think he might be getting escaped by the template package

Answer (score 16):

There is a problem elsewhere in your code - perhaps the output is being escaped when put into a template? The line you have posted will replace newlines with br and is correct - see this simple test:

```
package main
import("strings")

func main() {
    s := "I am a string\nContaining new lines"
    s = strings.Replace(s,"\n","<br>",-1)
    println(s)
}
```

You'd need to post more code than this for people to find where you are going wrong, for example post the function which creates/manipulates the string, and the bit of template where it is output to html.

On Go playground - http://play.golang.org/p/KMzxku4UtL

Comment: in this example `"\n"` is  literal string and is interpreted at compile time. Same with the `s` variable assigned string.  If the questioner's string was read in, say from a file, the '\' and 'n' would be separate literal characters and the replace would not work.

Comment: @Richard Huh? `"\n"` is a one-byte string containing only the newline character. This code does not replace a literal \ followed by `n`

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/296559/robotamer  got it right. Problem solved.

The problem is in the template file. I used |html to escape the contents. When I removed "|html" in the code, everything is fine.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It would be good to accept your own answer (or any answer at all) when it solves your problem. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for details.

Comment: This is a bad idea—you are now open to HTML injection vulnerabilities (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection). You are better off writing a loop in your template to loop over each line, and put a <br /> between.